# Firebase node.js application opens someone else's profile

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have a node.js application which I deployed as Firebase function. The issue that I am having is, if user1 is logged it from a window and user2 open the url in a seperate device+browser, User2 is automatically logged in as user1. I am not sure why this is happening.

Some things I have tried

1. Setting the Auth persistence to None.
2. Changing my session config in index.js which looks like

```
app.use(session({
    name: '__session',
    secret: 'random',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 5 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 5 days
        secure: false,
        httpOnly: true
    }
}));

app.use(flash());

app.use(async(req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.success = req.flash('success');
    res.locals.error = req.flash('error')
    res.locals.currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    next();
});
```

Anyone faced similar issue? Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**Session data is not saved in the cookie itself, just the session ID. Session data is stored server-side.**

Comment: What is the issue with this in that case?

Comment: it stored a session id in the backend. so any user request cookies  on your server mean it responds common things for all users

Comment: so you need to create cookies  in client side

Comment: I see. Do you have any code example you can point me to for some elaboration.